# javascript recursive function not working fully

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have the following recursive function but it doesnt work... 
It searches as far down as 'firstPageChild' and then finishes. Can anyone spot what is wrong here?.. 
I'm sure its something simple but its stumping me at the moment..

```
  var pageMap = [{"pageID" : "mainPage",
                        "children": [{"pageID" : "firstPage",
                                   "children": [{"pageID" : "firstPageChild",
                                                 "children": []
                                                }]
                                    },
                                    {"pageID" : "secondPage",
                                   "children": [{"pageID" : "secondPageChild1",
                                                 "children": []
                                                }, {"pageID" : "secondPageChild2",
                                                 "children": []
                                                }]
                                    },
                                    {"pageID" : "thirdPage",
                                   "children": [{"pageID" : "thirdPageChild1",
                                                 "children": []
                                                }, {"pageID" : "thirdPageChild2",
                                                 "children": []
                                                }]
                                    }]
                      }];

function findObjectById(root, id) {
debugger;
var k, pageVar;
if (root.children) {
    for (k in root.children) {

        pageVar = root.children[k];

        if (pageVar.pageID == id) {
            return pageVar;
        }
        else if (pageVar.children.length) {
            return findObjectById(pageVar, id);
        }
    }
}
};

for (var i = 0, len = pageMap.length; i < len; i++) {
  var myObj = findObjectById(pageMap[i], "secondPageChild2");
}


console.log(myObj);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3nkfbbyy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `return findObjectById(pageVar, id);` on the

```
pageSrch = findObjectById(pageVar, id);
if(pageSrch){
   return pageSrch;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hp3br5bv/)